# WebView Download Manager: How to download files with their default names?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a simple webview app using Android Studio. The webview app is booting a website that contains downloadable media files. For now, after downloading a file it save the file as fileName.
This is my Download manager

```
        String myCurrentUrl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    superWebView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

    superProgressBar.setMax(100);

    superWebView.loadUrl("http://www.hausadownload.blogspot.com");
    superWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    superWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){});
    superWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());


    superWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {

            DownloadManager.Request myRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            myRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "fileName");
            myRequest.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            myRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

            DownloadManager myManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            myManager.enqueue(myRequest);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your file is downloading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

I don't want it to be saving all files with the name "fileName". I want it to be saving files with their default names

Answer (score 0):

You should somehow be able to get the file name from the url like so:

```
String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.length());
```

Then just pass that in this line instead of hardcoded String "`filename`":

```
myRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
```

Comment: Please show me where to add "String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.length());" in my my dowlnoad manager?

Comment: in `onDownloadStart` man. Come on, that should have been pretty obvious.